# How do I see the computers I have accessed in the past through ssh?

Tags: windows-10, ssh

I remember that when I accessed other computers with `ssh` in the past from my windows PC for the first time, a message appeared saying something like "host added to this or that".

I would like to know where this info is stored. In other words where are the list of machines ips I have accessed in the past

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? My first guess would be some sort of MRU equivalent in the registry.

Comment: For comparison: in Linux a common SSH client is from OpenSSH and it uses `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. [You cannot simply get addresses from it though](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175199/108618).